# Pandas dataframe: Group by two columns and then average the third column

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe that looks like the example below:

```py
year    x   y
2016    o   227
2018    o   214
2016    o   56
2018    o   62
2018    o   87
2019    o   40
2017    r   15
2016    i   14
2016    o   88
2014    o   48
```

I want to get an output in which the average of **y** is computed based on a `grouby` on year and then further the `x`. Something like this:

```py
year    x   y
2016    o   (227 + 56 + 88)/3 = 123.66 = 124 (Need just the final value)
2018    o   (214 + 62 + 87)/3 = 121 (Need just the final value)
2019    o   40
2017    r   15
2016    i   14
2014    o   48
```

I think I found a way (but I could be wrong), to do it but the result comes out to be in a non dataframe:

```py
print(part_b[['year', 'x', 'y']].groupby(['year', 'x']).mean())
```

Output generated: (Results in the following output are from my entire data)

````py
            y
year x                                              
2014 o      48.000000
2016 i      14.000000
     o      117.000000
2017 o      71.000000
     r      27.500000
2018 i      23.000000
     o      97.428571
2019 i      11.000000
     o      115.500000
'''

Whereas I would like to have this:
```python
year x      y                                        
2014 o      48
2016 i      14
2016 o      117
2017 o      71
2017 r      28
2018 i      23
2018 o      97
2019 i      11
2019 o      116
'''
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this:

```
   year category  amount
0  2015        A     200
1  2015        B    1000
2  2015        A     300
3  2016        C    1200
4  2016        A     800
5  2016        A    2500
6  2016        B     100
```

Doing this:

```
df.groupby(['year','category'])['amount'].mean()
```

will give you:

```
    year  category
2015  A            250
      B           1000
2016  A           1650
      B            100
      C           1200
Name: amount, dtype: int64
```

To achieve what you needed, just do:

```
df.groupby(['year','category'])['amount'].mean().reset_index()

   year category  amount
0  2015        A     250
1  2015        B    1000
2  2016        A    1650
3  2016        B     100
4  2016        C    1200
```

Comment: Just a note to you, you should rename the column "amount" after you do reset_index(), cause it does not reflect what it meant